# Error with djigger in agent mode (java.io.InvalidClassException)

Tags: java, profiling, agent, djigger

When trying out the newer features of the develop branch in djigger, I'm running into the following exception (see below). Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Unexpected error
java.io.InvalidClassException: io.djigger.monitoring.java.model.ThreadInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2091258603924023895, local class serialVersionUID = 4152628234709390380
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.smb.core.MessageRouter.run(MessageRouter.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using an incompatible version of the agent.jar with the client. Try rebuilding the agent and redeploying.